# Remote SSH run local script containing sudo command, -T is not working

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I try to run a local script using ssh
`ssh remotehost 'bash -s' < test.sh`

test.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start Script"
sudo echo "test"
echo "End Script"
```

Also, in remote host, sudo logging is enabled in /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults logfile="/var/log/sudo.log"
Defaults log_input,log_output
```

After this, the output of `ssh remotehost 'bash -s' < test.sh` is

```
Start Script
test
```

Script got terminated after executing the first sudo command. But I need to get

```
Start Script
test
End Script
```

I also tried `ssh -T remotehost 'bash -s' < test.sh`, unfortunately it's not working.
What's the prope way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is that your actual script you are testing with or is there more, like `set -e`?

Comment: @jordanm: no there's no `set -e` in the script, even in user bash setting.